# Validity of LinearRing in shapely

Tags: shapely

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing


llpts = np.asarray([[18.5165    , 73.82883333],
       [18.51678333, 73.8279    ],
       [18.5156    , 73.82848333],
       [18.51586667, 73.82755   ],
       [18.5165    , 73.82883333]])

linring_ll = LinearRing(llpts)

print('linring_ll.is_valid =',linring_ll.is_valid)
```

Using Shapely 1.7.1 and Python 3.9.2 the above code prints 'True' on my computer even though it seems that the LinearRing crosses itself (I plotted it in Spyder). Is this a rounding / numerics issue? This goes away when I convert the points from lat/lon space to xy space using equirectangular projection.

The complete code follows:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing, LineString, Polygon


def convert_llpts_xypts(latlon,rad_earth,center_lat,projtype='equirectangular'):
    # convert from latlon space to xy space 
    # latlon must be in degrees
    # lat lon looks like [(lat1,lon1),(lat2,lon2)....]
    # lat lon needs to be a np array

    if (projtype == 'equirectangular'):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266809/convert-from-latitude-longitude-to-x-y
        _radconv          = np.pi/180.0  
        _rade_radconv     = rad_earth*_radconv
        _rade_radconv_cos = _rade_radconv*np.cos(center_lat*_radconv)

        _xx = _rade_radconv_cos*latlon[:,1]
        _yy = _rade_radconv*latlon[:,0]
        _xx = _xx[:,None]
        _yy = _yy[:,None]

        return np.hstack((_xx,_yy))

    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid projtype={projtype} in convert_llpts_xypts')

# points in lat/lon space
llpts = np.asarray([[18.5165    , 73.82883333],
       [18.51678333, 73.8279    ],
       [18.5156    , 73.82848333],
       [18.51586667, 73.82755   ],
       [18.5165    , 73.82883333]])

# compute a latitude close to the center of the polygon
center_lat = np.sum(llpts[0:4,0])/4.0

# convert points to xy-space
xypts = convert_llpts_xypts(llpts,6378137.0,center_lat)

# make LinearRings
linring_ll = LinearRing(llpts)
linring_xy = LinearRing(xypts)

print(f'validity of ring in lat/lon space = ', linring_ll.is_valid)
print(f'validity of ring in xy space = ', linring_xy.is_valid)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to convert to "xy space"?

Comment: This is a really odd case. OpenJUMP that is using JTS for validation accepts `LINEARRING ( 18.5165 73.82883333, 18.51678333 73.8279, 18.5156 73.82848333, 18.51586667 73.82755, 18.5165 73.82883333 )` but not similar linearrings that I digitize myself. I would try to access JTS or GEOS developers.

Comment: @Spacedman Added code that you requested.

Comment: @user30184  I'll try contacting the developers.

Comment: Now that I read the docs again it says "The validity test is meaningful only for Polygons and MultiPolygons. ```True``` is always returned for other types of geometries." Maybe I shouldn't be using ```is_valid``` on LinearRings. But it also seems that ```False``` is returned on LinearRings at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the underlying GEOS library, and its upstream parent JTS.  Reported as [JTS-736](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/issues/736)